# What's the difference between the two of the codes?

Tags: python, function, debugging

---

Second one shows IndexError: deque index out of range while the other runs perfectly, can someone explain the same?
The outputs should only be Yes or No.

```
from collections import deque
def check(d):
    while d:
        big = d.popleft() if d[0]>d[-1] else d.pop()
        if not d:
            return "Yes"
        if d[-1]>big or d[0]>big:
            return "No"

for i in range(int(input())):
    int(input())
    d = deque(map(int,input().split()))
    print(check(d))
```

```
from collections import deque

for i in range(int(input())):
    int(input())
    numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
    d = deque(numbers)
    n = len(numbers)
    
    while d:
        if d[0]>d[-1]:
            previous = d.popleft()
        else:
            previous = d.pop()
        
        if not d:
            answer = "Yes"
        if d[-1]>previous or d[0]>previous:
            answer = "No"
        
        print(answer)
```

Sample Input:
2
6
4 3 2 1 3 4
3
1 3 2

Comment: @MarkPlotnick sorry but if I do the suggested changes, the output is wrong,

Comment: Can you give some sample input that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I added the sample input in the question.

Comment: OK, some `break`s had to be added in the second program to make it  equivalent to the `return`s in the first program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first program:

```
while d:
    big = d.popleft() if d[0]>d[-1] else d.pop()
    if not d:
        return "Yes"
    if d[-1]>big or d[0]>big:
        return "No"
```

The `return` will exit the loop when either the deque is empty or the first or last elements are larger than the element just popped off.

But in your second program:

```
while d:
    if d[0]>d[-1]:
        previous = d.popleft()
    else:
        previous = d.pop()
    
    if not d:
        answer = "Yes"
    if d[-1]>previous or d[0]>previous:
        answer = "No"
```

The loop isn't exited until the deque is empty, but you want it to be exited as soon as you can determine the value for `answer`, just like your first program does. So there needs to be a `break` just after `answer` is set.

The error message you saw is due to the following: Both the second and third `if` statements are always executed. If `d` is empty, there will be a range error when the third `if` statement tries to access the first and last elements. The fix in the previous paragraph - adding `break` after `answer = "Yes"` - will also fix this error, but it wouldn't hurt to make the intent explicit by changing the third `if` to `elif`, so that it's only executed if `d` is nonempty.

Finally, `print(answer)` should be outside, rather than inside, the loop.

Here's a fixed version of the second program:

```
from collections import deque

for i in range(int(input())):
    int(input())
    numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
    d = deque(numbers)
    n = len(numbers)
    
    while d:
        if d[0]>d[-1]:
            previous = d.popleft()
        else:
            previous = d.pop()
        
        if not d:
            answer = "Yes"
            break
        elif d[-1]>previous or d[0]>previous:
            answer = "No"
            break
    
    print(answer)
```